# Upload de Multiplos Arquivos a partir de um celular

Tags: php, html, mobile, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

Olá,
Tenho uma aplicação web em que preciso enviar várias fotos ao mesmo tempo,
No pc vai sem problemas mas no celular eu não consigo selecionar múltiplas fotos.
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: a subir as fotos ou a resolver o problema? pra resolver o problema vai precisar colocar algumas informações, como o formulário HTML, qual servidor está... etc

Comment: Bom vou tentar ser claro, preciso de um formulário que faça upload de varias fotos ao mesmo tempo, tal formulário, eu já tenho e funciona quando não uso via mobile.

Comment: <form action="banco-prd.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="file" name="foto[]" class="form-control" multiple>
</form>
basicamente é o formulário que uso e funciona se usar um PC ou notebook;
Agora se eu for em um celular eu não consigo selecionar mais de uma foto por vez